# Unable to satisfy constraints with nested stack views

Tags: swift, nslayoutconstraint, uistackview

I'm slowly going insane trying to debug an `Unable to satisfy constraints` warning in the console, which appears when I transition from iPhone portrait to iPhone landscape. I'm working on a Dashboard-type view, with nested stack views. The top stack changes axis to .horizontal if the width size class is regular.

### View hierarchy:

- View

  - Scrollview

    - Base View

      - Dashboard stack view

        - Top stack view

          - Progress view
          - Stats view
        - Middle view
        - Bottom view

[image]

### Code

- All components have `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` in `viewDidLoad`
- Constraints are manipulated when size class change is detected

```
override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {

    setupDashboardView()
}

func setupDashboardView() {
    let sizeClass = self.traitCollection

    if sizeClass.isIpad {
        topStack.axis = .horizontal
        topStackHeight.constant = (self.dashboardStack.bounds.height*0.3)
        progressViewWidth.constant = (self.dashboardStack.bounds.width*0.25)
        progressViewHeight.isActive = false
    } else if sizeClass.isIphonePortrait {
        topStack.axis = .vertical
        topStackHeight.constant = self.view.frame.width*1.5
        progressViewWidth.isActive = false
        progressViewHeight.isActive = true
        progressViewHeight.constant = self.view.frame.width
    } else if sizeClass.isIphoneLandscape {
        progressViewHeight.isActive = false
        topStack.axis = .horizontal
        topStackHeight.constant = self.view.frame.height*0.5
        progressViewWidth.isActive = true
        progressViewWidth.constant = self.view.frame.width*0.25
        }
        dashboardStack.spacing = 5
        topStack.spacing = 5

        self.updateViewConstraints()
        self.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    }


extension UITraitCollection {
    var isIpad: Bool {
        return horizontalSizeClass == .regular && verticalSizeClass == .regular
    }
    var isIphoneLandscape: Bool {
        return verticalSizeClass == .compact
    }
    var isIphonePortrait: Bool {
        return horizontalSizeClass == .compact && verticalSizeClass == .regular
    }
    var isIphone: Bool {
        return isIphoneLandscape || isIphonePortrait
    }
}

//For constraint debugging
extension NSLayoutConstraint {
    override public var description: String {
        let id = identifier ?? ""
        return "id: \(id), constant: \(constant)"
    }
}
```

### Debugger output

This is received when I rotate iPhone from portrait to landscape.

```
[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "id: , constant: 0.0",
    "id: , constant: 0.0",
    "id: , constant: 0.0",
    "id: , constant: 0.0",
    "id: progressWidth, constant: 224.0",
    "id: s, constant: 5.0",
    "id: scrollTrail, constant: 5.0",
    "id: UIScrollView-frameLayoutGuide-width, constant: 0.0",
    "id: UISV-canvas-connection, constant: 0.0",
    "id: UISV-canvas-connection, constant: 0.0",
    "id: UISV-canvas-connection, constant: 0.0",
    "id: UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width, constant: 896.0",
    "id: UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide-left, constant: 44.0",
    "id: UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide-right, constant: 44.0"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
id: progressWidth, constant: 224.0

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2020-02-26 11:27:51.128311+0000 Haem Data PG Std[9632:2228108] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "id: progressHeight, constant: 414.0",
    "id: topStackHeight, constant: 185.0",
    "id: UISV-canvas-connection, constant: 0.0",
    "id: UISV-canvas-connection, constant: 0.0"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
id: progressHeight, constant: 414.0

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Comment: I do believe we need to see the constraints for the `TopStackView` and `ProgressView` in order to have an idea of what you are actually activating when the orientation is changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Constraints that are dependent on other layout actions can get tricky. Auto-layout makes multiple "passes" as it tries to satisfy all constraints.

This is particularly noticeable with proportional constraints and with constraints that can be affected by stack views (which are doing their own layout actions).

To avoid the warnings, you often need to tweak the constraint priorities.

And, you need to be careful about the order when you are activating / deactivating constraints.

I laid out the objects as you have shown, and for your case, you *should* be able to fix things by:

- change the Priority of `progressViewHeight`, `progressViewWidth` and `topStackHeight` constraints each to `999`.
- constraint changes order should be

  - setting `.isActive = false` on views/labels/etc should go first
  - changing `.constant` values on views/labels/etc should go next
  - followed by setting `.isActive = true` on views/labels/etc
  - followed by changing `.constant` values on stack views
  - and finally changing the `.axis` of stack views

Not all of those are hard-and-fast rules, but from experience that is a good way to go.

Try changing the Priorities on your constraints as listed above, and changing your `setupDashboardView()` func as follows:

```
func setupDashboardView() {
    let sizeClass = self.traitCollection

    if sizeClass.isIpad {
        progressViewHeight.isActive = false
        progressViewWidth.constant = (self.dashboardStack.bounds.width*0.25)
        topStackHeight.constant = (self.dashboardStack.bounds.height*0.3)
        topStack.axis = .horizontal
    } else if sizeClass.isIphonePortrait {
        progressViewWidth.isActive = false
        progressViewHeight.isActive = true
        progressViewHeight.constant = self.view.frame.width
        topStackHeight.constant = self.view.frame.width*1.5
        topStack.axis = .vertical
    } else if sizeClass.isIphoneLandscape {
        progressViewHeight.isActive = false
        progressViewWidth.constant = self.view.frame.width*0.25
        progressViewWidth.isActive = true
        topStackHeight.constant = self.view.frame.height*0.5
        topStack.axis = .horizontal
    }
    dashboardStack.spacing = 5
    topStack.spacing = 5

    // not needed
    //self.updateViewConstraints()

    // NEVER call this yourself
    //self.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
}
```